# Kafka + IoT use case + Stream Processing

Tags: iot, stream-processing

We have a number of drink machines which need to send telemetry/events to our central system and aso receive commands (e.g. power down/deactivate) from our central system.

Today our machines (which run an android operating system) call a REST API endpoint on our backend which will do something like update a backend database, redis cache, trigger a task. We return a HTTP 20X, 40X, 50X. I have little experience understanding just how this will scale... today we are 100s of machines with events coming through at an average rate of 5 per minute. As we connect to more machines (tens of thousands being manufactured as we speak), I'm not sure how ideal this solution is, or if using REST patterns/abstraction is the best option.

So first question - as we take in telemetry/events from the machine and perform some kind of processing on it, does this class as stream processing? One of the things which makes me hesitant to call it stream processing is that if a machine sent an event which causes an update to a database, and then if the database update failed, the machine would receive a 400/500 and that should prompt it to try again. With true stream processing I feel that it's just fire and forget - i.e. if the consumer failed your producer wouldn't be concerned. Your producer would only receive a success/fail code that the event was delivered, but not how it was processed.

2nd question - we have an inelastic ingestion pipeline. Calling a single API which then synchronously connects to our backend (database, redis) to update state means that contention on something like a database will impact ingestion. What we need to do is decouple the ingestion pipeline from writing to the database... e.g. having some kind of durable buffer between the API and the backend which accepts events and queues them up for processing on the backend. I am wondering if Kafka is a suitable technology here. I am new to this area, but after being overwhelmed by a day of research I keep hearing more and more about Kafka. MQTT & RabbitMQ are also mentioned prominently.

3rd - if we created a kafka cluster, do I need to host the kafka-rest proxy seperately to be able to make and send REST requests?

Other details: on AWS (guessing we can use Amazon MKS), backend (which would be a consumer) is TypeScript (i see there is a kafka-node node package).

Comment: 3) Yes, rest proxy would be separate, assuming you need it. Otherwise "Is Kafka appropriate here?" seems like an opinionated question.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if currently your clients (drink machines) are waiting for the response for each call, **and** that response indicates whether or not that the record has been fully processed (i.e. in its "final" form and location), then I believe most would agree its **not** really stream processing. But there is no architecture police, so in a sense "it is what you call it" :)

That being said, I would definitely not say that stream processing must be **fire-and-forget**. Your clients could still wait for responses from your API or message broker that the messages has been properly enqueued (i.e a "receipt" acknowledgement). That's not fire-and-forget.
From the information you have given I think it makes sense to consider such a stream-processing approach. For telemetry that's typically the case.

If such a message "receipt" acknowledgement isn't enough, and you for some reason **really** need the clients to re-send the data in case of failure, you can still consider using streams. E.g. by having additional streams for the processing status (id + ok/nok), which the back-end worker(s) write to. And when the client sends a message to your API, it gets back the status of the (older) processed messages so far, which it can inspect and act upon. It really depends on how critical your data is.

Secondly, if you are already using Redis, you might want to look into using it as a message broker as well. It has a quite powerful stream datatype and commands. https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro

It's very easy to mitigate concerns of data-loss in Redis, by using replicas and AOF writing etc, and you can scale it horizontally if/when you need it too.
But I would personally not start with a cluster, just as single shard and one or two replicas if I were you.
I would not have the clients talk directly to Redis, but only through your current API.

Thirdly, Kafka sounds overkill, and unnecessarily complex, for your use-case in my opinion.